# Uso do snippet nas respostas e perguntas

Tags: debate, stack-snippets

Há um snippet para texto nas respostas?

O editor de textos oferece o recurso para códigos html/js/css

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
```

Contudo, teria alguma forma de usarmos também para textos que não sejam códigos?

O intuito disso é poder deixar o snippet fechado para um comentário dentro de uma resposta, para que o usuário concentre-se mais no conteúdo visível e caso tiver interesse, ele olharia o que está escrito no snippet.

Nesses snippets, seria colocado uma observação adicional, uma opinião, uma recomendação de boa prática, etc. Coisas que se fossem colocadas junto a resposta, tornariam-na extensa com propensão a má interpretação ou tirando o foco principal.

Exemplo, eu fiz uma gambiarra para testar:

[Comando unlink não está funcionando se ativado via include](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117299/comando-unlink-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando-se-ativado-via-include/117321#117321)

Comment: Só teve um par de vezes que senti necessidade disso, e acho que era importante. Será que podemos criar uma nova tag Pedido-de-Gambiarra? :)

Answer (score 6):

O mais próximo disso é a marcação de *spoiler*, `>!`:

> Texto secreto aqui

Mas não faz sentido para o que você está querendo...

Tem os comentários abaixo do post, mas o comprimento dos comentários é limitado.

Por fim, você pode usar uma tag `<sup>` ou `<sub>` <sub>para deixar</sub> <sup>o texto com corpo menor</sup>.

E os snippets, como você citou.

**Qualquer uma dessas soluções é gambiarra**.

Comment: Tem também os comentários :)

Comment: Eu já esperava que alguém falasse sobre usar o espaço dos comentários. O que acontece muitas vezes é que espaço nos comentários é insuficiente. Tem que ser no corpo da resposta mesmo. O spoiler, por exemplo, em sistemas de foruns como o Invision Power Board (IPB), é padrão nas postagens e funciona como o snippet do SO. E serve justamente para isso que perguntei. Mas claro, não estou dizendo que tem que transformar o SO num forum.. é apenas um exemplo. Usei o termo snippet pois vi que não tem o termo spoiler aqui no SO. Pensei que o SO usasse o termo snippet ao invés de spoiler.

Comment: @Daniel, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: rsrsr.. usar `sup` / `sub` foi meio forçado.

Comment: Numa tela touch, o spoiler de texto secreto não funciona bem pois,  quando toca na tela o texto aparece e depois não desaparece.

Comment: Enquanto não tem tal recurso vou fazer algo mais simples. Na resposta, quando precisar, deixarei explítico que um determinado trecho é um comnetário adicional (opinião, crítica, recomendação). Editei na pergunta para deixar um exemplo mais claro.